# How to get different summation value for different row

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am building a marksheet form that will automatically calculate the total mark entered by a teacher. I am try to do this using jquery code. In a Table, row will dynamically added by php for loop. I want different result for different row. In this form one student for one row, Student list dynamically added in table row which is come from my database. **Note that: using different id or different class name for different row, it is not working because table row come dynamically.** 
[My code output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CikCT.png)

```
        <html>
        <head>    
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> 
      <title>Auto Sum Table</title>

     </head>

      <body>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
    });
      </script> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
    <td><p>1st subject</p></td>
   <td><p>2nd subject</p></td>
   <td><p>total mark</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="qty1" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="qty1" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="qty1" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="qty1" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
   </tr>
   </table>

    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: You've not shown any code at all that fills in data for your table. Assuming your are using php, why not just do the sum in php as you fill in the table?

Comment: is it possible do automatic summation without class or id name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict the calculation on the row. For this you have to first get the row (with e.g. [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)) where the changed `.qty1` is a child of:

```
const row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

Then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the inputs for the actual math:

```
const quantites = row.find(".qty1");
const total = row.find(".total");
```

Example:

```js
$(".qty1").on("input", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var quantities = row.find(".qty1");
    
    var result = 0;
    quantities.each(function() {
      result += +this.value;
    });
    
    row.find(".total").val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><p>1st subject</p></td>
    <td><p>2nd subject</p></td>
    <td><p>total mark</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```